# Power BI: calculated aggregate column using related tables

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have the following two tables:

[image]

I would like to add a calculated column to the `Author` table showing the total number of pages in all the books the author has written.

In SQL I would solve the problem by writing a view like this (or using that code in a trigger to populate the calculated column):

```sql
SELECT
    "Author"."Author ID"
    (SELECT sum("Page count") FROM Book WHERE "Author ID" = "Author"."Author ID") AS "Total pages" 
FROM "Author";
```

How to achieve something like that in Power BI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to add the column to the dimension table (one side of the one-to-many relationship) you'll have to use *RELATEDTABLE()* instead of the *RELATED()* function:

```
Page Count = SUMX(
    RELATEDTABLE(Book), 
    Book[Page Count]
)
```

The **row context** in your calculated column gets transfered to a **filter context** in the fact table (Books). This feature is know as **context transition**.

Of cause your SQL would rather return a table like this one:

```
Author Pages = 
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    Author, 
    "Author ID", Author[Author ID],
    "Page Count", SUMX(
        RELATEDTABLE(Book), 
        Book[Page Count]
    )
)
```

However, if you are just interested in visualizing the numbers you don't need any of the above expressions, but just have to drag *Author ID* and *Page Count* into a *Table* visual.

[image]